# Fund Separation Theorem for Performance Seeking Portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, performance-evaluation

Can someone explain this statement?

"The beauty of the fund separation theorem is that the performance seeking portfolio mandate is the same for all investors"

Comment: more background about fund separation theorem will be helpful.

Comment: @Gordon - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_fund_separation_theorem

Comment: The Wikipedia entry does not contain this statement. It is a strange statement. I assume that by the "performance seeking portfolio" they simply mean the risky portfolio, while the other portfolio is the risk free asset. It is a major result of basic portfolio theory that the risky portfolio is the same for all (under some assumptions...), though people hold it in different amount. Strange terminology though.